# How to make a arrow using rectangle and triangle in css

Tags: css

[image]

How do I make this arrow using css?

I'm not able to remove the border of the third side of the triangle

Here is what I have so far:

```css
    #arrowbox
    {
     width: 200px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color:white;
     margin-left:100px;
     margin-top:100px;
     position: relative;
     border-style:solid;
    }

    #arrowbox:after {
     left: 100%;
      top: 20%;

      content: " ";
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     border-style:solid;
     border-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0);
     border-left-color: black;
     border-width: 40px;
     margin-top: -25px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="arrowbox"></div>
```

Comment: Can you use two divs to make ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this using pseudo-element and gradient:

```css
.arrow {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  margin:50px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-right:none;
  position:relative;
}
.arrow:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  right:-50px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute; 
  right:0;
  top:-20px;
  bottom:-20px;
  width:1px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(#000,#000)top/100% 20px no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000)bottom/100% 20px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
</div>
```

You can also use polygon element of SVG to easily create it:

```css
svg polygon {
 stroke:#000;
 fill:transparent;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="300">
  <polygon points="0,20 0,80 200,80 200,100 300,50 200,0 200,20"  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the `clip-path` property, however, its not widely supported at this time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

```css
#arrowbox {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 35%, 75% 35%, 75% 25%, 99% 50%, 75% 75%, 75% 65%, 0% 65%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 35%, 75% 35%, 75% 25%, 99% 50%, 75% 75%, 75% 65%, 0% 65%);
}
```

```html
<div id="arrowbox"></div>
```

---

For those looking for an SVG option, this would give you the luxury of filling it with a color if you wish, or add other styling attributes as needed:

```css
svg { width: 150px; height: 150px; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
  <path d="M 1,35 75,35 75,25 99,50 75,75 75,65 1,65z" /> 
</svg>

<hr>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="green" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2">
  <path d="M 1,35 75,35 75,25 99,50 75,75 75,65 1,65z" /> 
</svg>
```